# SQL Code to display data matching on 3 conditions

Tags: sql, teradata

Need to display the number of days elapsed of patients who were admitted to a skill nursing facility, discharged to their homes (with or without care) and was admitted to a hospital or Emergency Room.

I was asked to display the number of days elapsed of patients who were admitted to a skill nursing facility, discharged to their homes (with or without care) and was admitted to a hospital or Emergency Room. The metric is to assess the effectiveness of skilled nursing facilities ability to keep patients from being readmitted to hospitals or seen in the emergency room after leaving a nursing facility.

I have a much larger query that works great using FOLLOWING and PRECEDING that gives me previous facility and next facility admitted, but it doesn't help with the issue above. I know a need another subquery, but the one I have just isolated the latest and earliest. I need it to be rolling and looking for the first instance that meets the condition. I was asked to either give days or insert the date of last admission.

```
select nursing.*, hospital.*
from
(Select--nursing stays only
SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID
, SUMMARY.POS
, SUMMARY.ADMIT_DATE
, SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE
, SUMMARY.Discharge_To

FROM PRD.SUMMARY

INNER JOIN

(Select 
SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID, MAX(DISCHARGE_DATE) MX_DISCHARGE_DATE

FROM PRD.SUMMARY
WHERE

SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
  And SUMMARY.POS = 'Nursing' 
group by SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID) sq 

ON sq.MEMBER_ID = SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID and sq.MX_DISCHARGE_DATE = SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE
WHERE

SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
  And SUMMARY.POS = 'Nursing') nursing 

INNER JOIN

( --hospital stays only
Select
SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID
, SUMMARY.POS
, SUMMARY.ADMIT_DATE
, SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE
, SUMMARY.Discharge_To

FROM PRD.SUMMARY

INNER JOIN (

select MEMBER_ID, MIN(ADMIT_DATE) MIN_ADMIT_DATE

FROM PRD.SUMMARY

WHERE
SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' And SUMMARY.POS = 'Hospital'

GROUP BY SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID) sq 

on sq.MEMBER_ID = SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID and sq.MIN_ADMIT_DATE = SUMMARY.ADMIT_DATE

WHERE
SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-12-31' And SUMMARY.POS = 'Hospital')

hospital on nursing.MEMBER_ID = hospital.MEMBER_ID and nursing.DISCHARGE_DATE >= hospital.ADMIT_DATE
```

DDL to create the above table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[jpsSUMMARY](
    [member_id] [int] NULL,
    [pos] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [admit_date] [date] NULL,
    [discharge_date] [date] NULL,
    [discharge_to] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
GO
```

CSV data corresponding to the Expected Output

```
member_id,pos,admit_date,discharge_date,discharge_to
1001,Nursing   ,2016-03-08,2016-03-14,Home Without Care                                 
1001,Hospital  ,2016-03-21,2016-03-24,Home Without Care                                 
1001,ER        ,2016-03-27,2016-03-28,Hospital                                          
1001,Nursing   ,2016-08-19,2016-09-02,Home Without Care                                 
1001,ER        ,2016-09-05,2016-09-06,Home Without Care
```

[Here is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLOo6.png)

Comment: ExpectedOutput has 7 columns that are from "much larger query that works great" but that sql is not given to us.
The sql that is shown filters only Nursing and Hospital.  The sql also filters greater than 2017 (not any 2016 in jpg).
If you want us to help you, please share the larger sql.  Also, additional test data would be appreciated.

Comment: Correct, donPablo. The subquery does put out 7 columns, but the example output is just that - an example. The filters for nursing and hospital is to try to pick all nursing facilities and match it against hospitals for next admission. I thought if I could get that to work, I can then add the ER too. The query(ies) will be connected in Tableau and I would either need to join the two separate queries or get a subquery to work in this main query:

Comment: Select
    , SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID as "Member ID"
    , SUMMARY.POS
    , SUMMARY.ADMIT_DATE as "Admit Date"
    , SUMMARY.STAY_ID as "Stay ID"
    , SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE as "Discharge Date"
    , SUMMARY.Discharge_To as "Discharge To"
    , SUMMARY.LOS
    , SUMMARY.Days_From_Last_Hospital_DC as "Days from Last Hospital Discharge"
    , MAX(SUMMARY.STAY_ID) OVER
 (partition by SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID 
 order by SUMMARY.STAY_ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as "Previous Stay ID"

Comment: , Max(SUMMARY._DISCHARGE_DATE) OVER
 (partition by SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID 
 order by SUMMARY.STAY_ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as "Previous Stay Discharge Date"
    , Max(SUMMARY.POS) OVER
 (partition by SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID 
 order by SUMMARY.STAY_ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as "Previous POS"
    , Max(SUMMARY.Discharge_To) OVER
 (partition by SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID 
 order by SUMMARY.STAY_ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as "Previous Discharge To"

Comment: , Max(SUMMARY.POS) OVER
 (partition by SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID 
 order by SUMMARY.STAY_ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) as "Next Immediate POS"
    , Max(SUMMARY.ADMIT_DATE) OVER
 (partition by SUMMARY.MEMBER_ID 
 order by SUMMARY.STAY_ID ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) as "Next Immediate Admit Date"
 
    From PRD.SUMMARY

    Where SUMMARY.DISCHARGE_DATE BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2018-09-30' and SUMMARY.STAY_ID IS NOT NULL

Comment: Sorry... not sure else how to post the full query at once due to limits in comments box size.

Comment: Can you add some more example data and explain in more detail what result you want & why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to re-constitute that sql, and then prettyprint to look at it.
Try this to see if it is any simpler.  Do all the OVER's once in the CTE...  You may want to remove the ISNULL(CAST(... and accept the results as 0 (zero).

revised May10 noon pos -> [pos]

```
WITH  SumRN as
(SELECT 
       member_id
      ,[pos]
      ,admit_date
      ,discharge_date
      ,discharge_to
      ,ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By member_id order by discharge_date, admit_date) as rn
  FROM PRD.SUMMARY  --jpsSUMMARY
 )

SELECT
     s1.member_id
    ,s1.[pos]
    ,s1.admit_date
    ,s1.discharge_date
    ,s1.discharge_to
    ,ISNULL(sp.[pos],'') as Previous
    ,ISNULL(sf.[pos],'') as Next

    ,ISNULL(cast(case when sp.[pos] = 'Nursing' and sp.discharge_to Like 'Home%' and s1.[pos] = 'Hospital'  
           Then Datediff(d, sp.discharge_date, s1.admit_date) Else null End  as varchar(10)), '') as DaysNursingHosp
    ,ISNULL(cast(case when sp.[pos] = 'Nursing' and sp.discharge_to Like 'Home%' and s1.[pos] = 'ER'        
           Then Datediff(d, sp.discharge_date, s1.admit_date) Else null End  as varchar(10)), '') as DaysNursingER
 From          SumRN s1
 Left Join     SumRN sp
                  on s1.RN - 1 = sp.RN 
 Left Join     SumRn sf
                  on s1.RN + 1 = sf.RN
```

Results--

```
member_id   pos admit_date  discharge_date  discharge_to        Previous    Next    DaysN2Hosp  DaysN2ER
1001    Nursing     2016-03-08  2016-03-14  Home Without Care               Hospital        
1001    Hospital    2016-03-21  2016-03-24  Home Without Care   Nursing     ER          7   
1001    ER          2016-03-27  2016-03-28  Hospital            Hospital    Nursing         
1001    Nursing     2016-08-19  2016-09-02  Home Without Care   ER          ER              
1001    ER          2016-09-05  2016-09-06  Home Without Care   Nursing                          3
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Right now, I am trying to reconcile the sf.* and sp.* as I am getting error of "Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3706 : 42000] Syntax error: Data Type "pos" does not match a Defined Type name."

Comment: You will need to post the sql that is being executed.  I do not see " sf.* and sp.*" is the solution sql.  Maybe "pos" in your version of the db is a reserved word, and in that case, change all "pos"  to  "[pos]"  to make it a column name and not a keyword.

Comment: Rows 16 and 17 introduces "sp.pos" and "sf.pos" and sp and sf shows up in each row after row 18.

Comment: Is this a continuation of Syntax error?  Are Rows 16/17/18 referring to SQL or to Summary table input or to output? It is impossible for me to "see" what is being referred to.  Please be specific and post more info, such as SQL or Input data or Output results.

Comment: Sorry - I was referring back to your post where you provided the cleaned up coding after I posted my main code in several comments.

Comment: So that I am more clear, I took your last pasted coding, brought it over to Teradata and it showed no errors. It started to run, but stops with the notice that "pos" is not a defined type name. I isolated that at row 18 of your pasted query.

Comment: I have changed sql to enclose pos in brackets to prevent it from being a keyword (ala Type) and force it to be a column. Try copy/paste again.

Comment: Your answer is for SQL Server using some non-Standard SQL syntax, e.g. `[]` instead of `""`. In Teradata `pos` is not a keyword, but `"next"` and `"summary"` :-) The error is caused by `ISNULL`which must be replaced with `COALESCE`. And finally there's no `datadiff(...)`, should be `s1.admit_date - sp.discharge_date`  instead.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for solving the database differences.  Yes, I was using sqlserver. Please submit the Teradata solution.

Comment: I thank you both for the assistance. I have incorporated all the corrections and now have moved on to other errors. I am putting this on hold for now as it moved to a lower priority. Once I get more familiar with Teradata, I should be able to figure out why I can't get the query to run. Take care.